# Search for a value in json from other json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im trying to search a value from a json in other json and then create a new object from unmatched values.

Here my code:

```
var anis_report = [ { ani: '525510107835', Times_repeated: 11, Minutes: '33.97' },{ ani: '526642111071', Times_repeated: 9, Minutes: '6.00' },{ani: '524499765316', Times_repeated: 8, Minutes: '31.20' },{ ani: '525517421550', Times_repeated: 7, Minutes: '167.10' }]

var anis_whitelisted_db = [{ ani: '525510107835' },{ ani: '525555742933' },{ ani: '525511049249' },{ ani: '524422242668' }]
```

Here Im getting the ani value from anis_report to search that value in anis_whitelisted_db but is not working as I espected.

```
  for (ani in anis_whitelisted_db) {
    for (ani_2 in anis_report) {      
      if (anis_report[ani_2]['ani'] !== anis_whitelisted_db[ani]['ani']) {
        // Push unmatch object
        anis_not_whitelisted.push(anis_report[ani_2])     
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tag `java' by mistake ? That looks like a Python construct.

Comment: my bad, it's javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [for..of](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-for-of/) to loop through the elements then check for the matching value using the [.some](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp) method and finally remove the matching element using [.splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method:

```
var anis_report = [ { ani: '525510107835', Times_repeated: 11, Minutes: '33.97' },{ ani: '526642111071', Times_repeated: 9, Minutes: '6.00' },{ani: '524499765316', Times_repeated: 8, Minutes: '31.20' },{ ani: '525517421550', Times_repeated: 7, Minutes: '167.10' }]

var anis_whitelisted_db = [{ ani: '525510107835' },{ ani: '525555742933' },{ ani: '525511049249' },{ ani: '524422242668' }]

var anis_not_whitelisted=anis_report
for (const[i,ani] of anis_report.entries()) {
  if(anis_whitelisted_db.some( element => element['ani'] === ani['ani'] )){
    anis_not_whitelisted.splice(i,1)
  }
}

console.log(anis_not_whitelisted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an array with `for..of`

I think there is a logic issue too as you check every item in anis_whitelisted_db and, you must stop to iterate as soon as you have a match for a given ani.

Without any performance optimization (using Set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const whitelistedAnis = new Set(['ani1', 'ani2', 'ani3']);

for (const ani of anis_report) { // here ani is the { ani: xxx, Times_repeated, ...} object

   if (!whitelistedAnis.has(ani.ani)) anis_not_whitelisted.push(ani.ani);
}
```

This way, you manage only a list of anis and check whether or not a report's ani is in this list.